# Multiple variables in for loop in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to write a for loop in Go with multiple variables.

Coming from the javascript world, I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
    var i = 10;
    var b = 2;
    for (var a = b; i; i /= 2, b *= b ) {
      // some code
    }
```

I've tried a 'raw translation' like this:

```
   i, b := 10, 2
   for a := b; i; i /= 2, b *= b {
      // some code
    }
```

But it doesn't work. What is the proper syntax?

Many thanks!

Comment: Where is `i` defined in your Javascript code?

Comment: ive edited the code for clarity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Go, you can do multiple variable assignment in a loop like so.

```
package main

func main() {
    var (
        i = 10
        b = 2
    )
    for a := b; i != 0; i, b = i/2, b*b {
      // some code
    }
}
```